# how to get the count of matching rows and updating it into the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thank you in advance.

I have a table1 :

```
ID   ||   Values1   ||   Values2 ||
1    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
2    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
3    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
4    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
5    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
6    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
7    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
8    ||   ABC0001   ||    layer1 ||
9    ||   ABC0002   ||    layer1 ||
10   ||   ABC0002   ||    layer1 ||
11   ||   ABC0002   ||    layer1 ||
12   ||   ABC0002   ||    layer1 ||
```

I need to find the distinct count of **Values1** and update.
(the count of column **values1** will not exceed 12)

I have only 12 records in this table. For Exmaple if it has only one particluar set of **values1** like **ABC0001** then it should give me count as 12 and update it in a new row, but if their are more than one(ABC0001 and ABC0002) **Values1** then it should give me the separate count of both the **values1**

output:

table2:

```
 values1   ||   Count
 ABC0001   ||   8
 ABC0002   ||   4
```

I tried doing it using case statements but was unable to do it.

i am using MSSQL 2012
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `Select Values1, Count(Values1) from table1 Group by Values1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP BY Clause :

```
SELECT Values1 , COUNT(Values1)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Values1
```

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find full answer, with update another table:

```
-- insert output into temp table
SELECT Values1 , COUNT(Values1) as Count
into #temp
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Values1 
GO

-- update second table based on values from above output
update b
set Count = t.Count
from your_table2 b
    inner join #temp t
    on b.Values1 = t.Values1

-- drop temp table
drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Using window function we can get the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT Values1,
     COUNT(Values2) OVER(PARTITION BY Values1) As COUNTS 
FROM YourTablename
```

Result

```
Values1 COUNTS
--------------
ABC0001 8
ABC0002 4
```